# Will running Products and Technology Configuration Wizard > repair on one farm server make whole farm unavailable?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, moss

To fix an issue, I want to run the Products and Technology Configuration Wizard > Repair on an ***external*** server, but want to verify that the farm's ***internal*** sites won't be affected while it's running.

Can anyone confirm that running it won't make the internal sites unavailable?

Answer (score 0):

Running the Wizard may need to reset:

- IIS
- Timer Service
- Admin Service

So, it's very possible, depending on your configuration that the internal sites **WILL** be affected.

TBH, the wizard is normally only used for quick setups and demos. Once you have SharePoint up and running, there's is hardly ever a reason to use it again. Everything can be manually setup with little or no fuss without it.